# My java Applet not running on the main, why?

Tags: java

I tried to run the app from MAIN, but it does not work, if there is some kind of method that can cause the app run, I would like to hear, or something else that makes sure it does not run.

App.java (here its run)

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class App extends Applet {

public void paint(Graphics a1) {

    a1.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    a1.drawString("Hello", 50, 50);
}

public void init() {

    setSize(600, 300);

    setVisible(true);

    repaint();


}

}
```

MAIN.java (here just the frame run but the app not)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.io.Console;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public abstract class MAIN implements ActionListener{

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    JFrame f1 = new JFrame("My Frame");

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();

    JButton b1 = new JButton("Click Me!");

    JTextField tf1 = new JTextField("Write Here" , 40);

    JTextPane tp1 = new JTextPane();

    JTextPane tp2 = new JTextPane();

    JCheckBox cb1 = new JCheckBox();

    JColorChooser cc1 = new JColorChooser();


    f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    f1.getContentPane().add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    f1.pack();

    f1.setSize(800, 400);


    f1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);



    f1.setVisible(true);



    ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\W7-Admin\\workspace\\PROJECT\\imgs\\Icon1.png");

    f1.setIconImage(img1.getImage());

    p1.add(b1);

    p1.add(tp1);

    p1.add(tp2);

    p1.add(tf1);

    p1.add(cb1);

    //p1.add(cc1,BorderLayout.EAST);

    p1.setVisible(true);

    b1.setVisible(true);

    cc1.setVisible(true);

    tf1.setVisible(true);

    tf1.setSize(200,20 );

    b1.setLocation(50, 50);

    f1.setSize(0, 0);

    tp1.setText("TEXT: ");

    tp2.setText("checkbox");

    f1.setSize(800, 400);

    cb1.setText("CheckBox");


    App a1 = new App();

    a1.setSize(600, 300);

    a1.setVisible(true);

    a1.repaint();

    a1.init();


    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

            System.out.println("You clicked the button");
        }
    });   

    tf1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

            System.out.println("TEXT: " + tf1.getText());
            tp1.setText("TEXT: " + tf1.getText());
        }
    });   

     cb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

                if(e.getSource()==cb1){

                    if(cb1.isSelected()) {

                       System.out.println("chosed");
                       tp2.setText("chosed");


                    } else {

                        System.out.println("not chosed");
                        tp2.setText("not chosed");

                    }
                }
            }
        });   
}
}
```

Comment: Applets in Java can't be run from a main method as you can with other Java applications. You either need to embed them in a browser or other applet container, or run them with `appletviewer`.

Comment: Applets are suppose to be embedded within a browser. You should also avoid mixing heavy and light weight components, this will result in some serious glitches